# Limiting BeautifulSoup output

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have been working semi-successfully with BeautifulSoup and Selenium for some weeks now. However I have found myself in a situation I cannot untangle.

I need to extract the html from the first 6 rows or so out of a table. These rows do not share any class, id or similar.

Table structure:

```
  <table class="Table">
    <tr class="Table_Header">
        <td colspan="2">Some Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Class2">Some Text</td>
        <td><span class="Class"></span>Some Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Class2">Some Text</td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Class2">Some Text</td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="Class3">
        <td class="Class2"> Some Text </td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>   
        <tr class="Class3">
            <td class="Class2">Some Text</td>
            <td>Some Text</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td class="Class2">Some Text</td>
            <td>            <div class="Class4">Some Text</div>
            <div class="Class4">Some Text</div>
</td>
        </tr>
```

The table goes on and on, maintaining this structure but with seemingly random classes popping in and out.

Basically I would need to return the first six tr . I have tried several methods that either return the entire table or a single tr.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to get the first 6 tr  from a table? If I understand the question correctly I had a similar problem where I needed to get the first 400 td. Perhaps the code below would help?

Maybe something like

```
for row in get_log().findAll('tr'):
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        print (cell.text)
        logfile.write('{}\n'.format(cell.text))
        i += 1
    if i == 400:
        break
```

Also let me point you at the article I used to solve my own problem, the good stuff is near the end as it assumes you know literally nothing. 
https://first-web-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

EDIT:
Using the table on Boone County as a source:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/JailResidents/JailResidents.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'collapse shadow BCSDTable'})

i = 0
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    print (row.prettify())
    i += 1
    print i
    if i == 6:
        break
```

This outputs a ton of information, so I won't post it.Maybe you want to refine what you want from within each tr?

Comment: Thanks! 
Yes, get the first 6 tr from a table is exactly what I need. 
For some reason, this seems to get the entire table... 
I am obviously doing something wrong.
I'll check the article, thanks!

Comment: I did something similar to your problem but with the Boone County table.
Something to consider is, are you actually doing it wrong or are you just outputting all of what's in each
    
    tr

Comment: The article you sent highlighted what I was doing wrong. I got the results I wanted after combining that with your answer.
**My problem:**
What I had:
`table = soup('table', attrs={'class': 'resultsTable'})`
What I needed to have:
`table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'resultsTable'})`